# Renaming multiple files with no pattern

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm starting to learn how to use the CMD in Windows. And I have a directory full of documents with names like "Document_1.txt", "Document_5.txt" etc... (All with Document_#.txt but there's no pattern in the numbers).

I want to move each file to a folder named "Text_#" and change the name of the file to "text_#.txt". How can I do that?

My attempt is this (simple) batch file (actually I think I don't even need to create a batch file, but was easy to do this way.)

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,24) DO (
FORFILES /M *.txt /C "cmd /c IF @fname==Document_%%i (MD Text_%%i) & (MOVE @file Text_%%i\text_%%i.txt)"
```

The problem is that the IF command never returns true, although when writing ECHO @fname it prints "Document_#", so I suppose that even if what I see is the same there is some difference that I cant see using the ECHO command.

Anybody could give me some solution to this problem?

Comment: I wouldn't state that they have no pattern. In my opinion each filename begins with the same string `Document_`, which is in turn succeeded by either one or two integers only, and is then suffixed with the same extension `.txt`! I assume what you meant was that the numbers may not have every possible combination of a numeric sequence.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the simplest way is to forget about using the `ForFiles` command for this, and use a `For /F` loop instead. To ensure that only the files with a `.txt` extension whose basename ends with `_#` or `_##`, *(where `#` represents an integer)*, use the `Dir` command and filter its results with the help of `FindStr`. Then you can use `MD` to make the directories if it don't already exist and move the files into it, renaming them with their new name.

From the [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) with the current directory as that holding your files:

```batch-file
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=_" %G In ('Dir /B /A -D Document_??.txt ^| %__AppDir__%findStr.exe /I "_[0123456789]*\.txt$"') Do @If Not Exist Text_%~nH (MD Text_%~nH) & Move /Y %G_%H Text_%~nH\text_%H 1>NUL
```

If you want to do that from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) instead, also within the same current directory:

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=_" %%G In (
    'Dir /B /A -D Document_??.txt ^| %__AppDir__%findStr.exe /I "_[0123456789]*\.txt$"'
) Do @(
    If Not Exist Text_%%~nH MD Text_%%~nH
    Move /Y %%G_%%H Text_%%~nH\text_%%H 1>NUL
)
```

The above answers assume either one or two digits at the end of the file basenames, *(as you were limiting yours to numbers from `1` to `24` inclusive)* I have also left out quoting because your provided names didn't warrant it. If those were not truly representative, you'll need to introduce those as necessary and make any other changes which were outside of the question posed.